# how could I read/parse an object list of javascript using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am currently trying to figure out how to parse this, yet, no solution found.

My problem is that I am getting a object on this way: (this is a console.debug result)

```
[Object { id=32193, value="user 1"},
 Object { id=42203, value="user 3"}, 
Object { id=41747, value="user 4"} .....]
```

I tried with this function thinking could be json format

> http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

but no result yet.. any idea which is the best way to do it?

THanks

Comment: Please show the code you want to execute on this object. This shows the context, server or client. PHP is server context, and Javascript is client context, so it takes special measures to interact one with the other.

Comment: thanks, I dont know how the other code is made, I just receive it on an ajax call they are making sending me the object and I should use that information...

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript object. To convert it into PHP object, convert this javascript object into a JSON string.

`var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);`
// pass this string to PHP,

in PHP use `json_decode($jsonStr)` ( where $jsonStr is received through GET or POST.